# Are there languages that disallow initial vowels and lack glottal stop?

Tags: phonology, syllables, phonotactics, phoneme-inventories

Which, if any, of the world's languages have both the following features?

1. Syllable-initial vowels are disallowed; all syllables must begin with a consonant.
2. There is no glottal stop phoneme.

Answer (score 2):

As reported by Lin (1977) (*Phonology* 14:403-436), there is no glottal stop and no initial vowels in Piro. If you can get *Thargari Phonology and Morphology* (T. Klokeid 1969, Pac. Ling. Series B #12), you can confirm or deny whether that too is an example.

Comment: So the language is Thargari? You might want to make that more clear in your first sentence. Doing a google search came up with this link which supports that all syllables in Thargary have an onset: https://books.google.com/books?id=unyn2D4Gy4IC&pg=PA205&lpg=PA205&dq=Thargari&source=bl&ots=LoaVycX8Zx&sig=_V7nrwfSkzP9zNXe7thV-Iu_NBE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aTaOVYbdOJGxogSQ1LnADg&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=Thargari&f=false

Comment: I have the publication by Terry Klokeid and can confirm that Tharrkari (the spelling preferred by the people) syllables are all C initial. Also, it does not have glottal stop (few languages do in Western Australia).

Comment: But I'm sure there are plenty of other languages that require C initial syllables and don't have glottal stop, probably many such in Australia.

Comment: I wonder if it has homorganic glide + vowel syllables though, like /ji/ and /wu/. Those seem to occur in Dyirbal, another Australian language that is said to have no syllable-initial vowels.

Answer (score 2):

There's an Australian language **[Lardil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lardil_language)** that has both of the features the OP is asking for:

- there's [no phonemic glottal stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lardil_language#Phonology), in fact, there are no glottal consonants
- each syllable [starts with a consonant](https://books.google.com/books?id=JGBrYc-eJpMC&pg=PA120&dq=Lardil+syllable+structure&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzm8iFh97wAhVeQUEAHb-TCqEQ6AEwAHoECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=Lardil%20syllable%20structure&f=false) (there may be exceptions, but I don't think there are any in Lardil)